# Form closing when using this.hide()

Tags: c#, winforms, show-hide

Whenever i use this.Hide(); the form closes and does not just hide??
I am planning to use this.Hide(); to minimize my form to the system tray.

This closes the form..

```
 private void label14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();

    }
```

This form is the second form that starts up, and it is called from the first form like this:

```
Form frm = new Main();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

I did try to use frm.Show(); but then the program terminates again..
So the problem lies in the way the form is first started i would guess?

EDIT: I had to change the way the form was called.
I had to use this.hide instead of this.close on the first form.

Comment: Why not just set `this.WindowState` instead.. ?

Comment: How do you know that it closes?

Comment: Visual studio shows Start, instead of pause and stop when debugging.
And the process in task manager disappears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this instead:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Actually when use Hide(), the form is still open but hidden somewhere. So in my opinion using Hide() method and creating a new object again to show the form is not the right move. To switch between them, it is better to make a form manager class.

According to the comment, this may solve the problem (if simply calling the Show() method cannot be applied) :

```
 Form1 form = Application.OpenForms["Form1"] as Form1 ;
 if (form != null)
 {
     form.Show(); 
 }
```

Comment: Well, as i am planning to minimize it to system tray i dont want it to be shown on the taskbar.

Comment: @user2725580 in this case you have to make a form manager class or view the edit

Answer (score 0):

Hide method set visibility only.
Close also dispose internal objects!